# Trigger a button click when the space bar is pressed

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Now using (click) on the button, but how i want to use click and enter/space bar too.

Button (click)=“ShuffleClick()”

Comment: Why don't you use an `eventListener` and listen for a `keyup` for the `key 32` (spacebar)?

Comment: You can check out  [eventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) and its onkeypress event or any other HTML DOM event that fits your usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Hostlistener` to track the event.

```
import {Component, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
export class Component {

    @HostListener('window:keydown.Space', ['$event'])
    listenSpace(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
        alert('Space button pressed');
        this.ShuffleClick();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: where to put the event listener?

Comment: You can your code with mine. (modification in line 2.)

Comment: In the function of ShuffleClick  typescript, what should i put?

Comment: It should be the same as what you do with click event.

Comment: @IzzatiAzlan I updated the answer, is might be what you want. the previous will be active only when you focus on the element.

Comment: tq, it working on first button now. the second and third not working. but tq so much

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do anything, the browser already does that for you.

`<button>` and `<a>` elements are natively focusable, f.e. by means of the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and the browser will dispatch a `click` event when users use <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>.

[Activation behavior of elements of the HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#activation) explains:

> The user agent should allow the user to manually trigger elements that have an activation behavior, for instance using keyboard or voice input, or through mouse clicks. When the user triggers an element with a defined activation behavior in a manner other than clicking it, the default action of the interaction event must be to fire a click event at the element.

On macOS users can opt for skipping `<a>` links in the tab sequence.

You could manually bind to `(keydown.Space)="ShuffleClick()"` to do something else, but that is a bad idea since users’ expectation is for the button to do the same thing when clicked and activated by means of keyboard.